# Call Boost libraries in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have built the Boost library from these instructions:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529163/install-boost-library-in-visual-c-2008
```

Directory of the unzipped Boost folder is `C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0`. I have called  Visual C++ 2010. How to use Boost in a program?

I mean I want the following.

```
#include<boost>
```

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.org/483007 for inspiration and precise your question if anything didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak your project properties to add `C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0` to the include path and maybe the link path if you plan to use the part of Boost that is not include-only (`libboost_filesystem` for instance).

Comment: i have created  now project name of  which  is boost  what to do?

Comment: Actually the include path should contain C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0\boost (the headers are in the "boost" directory inside the "boost_num_version" main directory usually (it was the case for all versions of boost I have worked with)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the header path and library path in your project.

Also `#include <boost>` won't do anything. You have to include each individual feature of boost that you need. For instance if you need to link to the filesystem.lib file in to boost directory, and use `#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"`.

Take a look at this answer from step 6: [Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: i am confused  i did not understand well  so i have boost library keept on desktop yes?i  have built  all   boost library and i have visual c++ 2010 in which i i have created project name of which is boost what to do next and important how?steps i need please